# AWS EC2 process started with user data is reading wrong open files limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm using CloudFormation to create an autoscaling group. The autoscaling launch configuration specifies some bash commands in the instances' User Data to run on instance launch. The AMI I specify in my launch config is configured with 100000 max files (both in /etc/security/limits.conf and /etc/sysctl.conf). However a process that I start inside User Data is reading a limit of 2048. When I ssh into the instance and start the process, either as ec2-user or root user, I get the expected 1000000 max open files.

I really need that process to have the expected open file limit; I am really confused as to whats going on; Any ideas? Or suggested workarounds?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your user-data script is ran as root? That might be a permissions problem

Comment: @spg Hi yes its ran as root; also the open file limit is set to 1000000 for all users. Also here's what aws docs say about user data: "Scripts entered as user data are executed as the root user, so do not use the sudo command in the script"

Comment: Try `ulimit -n 1000000 ` in the script?

Comment: Wow that works. So weird. Thanks!